# Sqlalchemy doesn't create schema from metadata

Tags: python, database, orm, sqlalchemy

I want to create a database schema out and insert data with SQLalchemy. But for some reason SQLAlchemy doesn't apply the schema in `create_fixture.py`. SQLAlchemy raises an error when I commit my session because it can't find any tables.

Here a simplified version of my code.
My `__init__.py`:

```
  from sqlalchemy import create_engine                                                           
  from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session                                        
  from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base                                        

  engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres@localhost/syncer', echo=True)                    
  Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)                                                           
  session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(engine))
```

`entity.py`:

```
  from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer                                                                            
  from __init__ import Base, session    


  class Zone(Base):                                                               
         __tablename__ = 'zone'                                                      

         id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)                                      
         name = Column(String(50))
```

`create_fixture.py`

```
 from __init__ import Base, session                                                                                
 from entity import Zone                                                                           
 from sqlalchemy import create_engine                                                         

 Base.metadata.create_all() 
 zone = Zone('zone_1')
 session.add(zone)
 session.commit()
```

The output

```
   2013-09-13 20:06:12,340 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select version()
    2013-09-13 20:06:12,341 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
    2013-09-13 20:06:12,345 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select current_schema()
    2013-09-13 20:06:12,345 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
    2013-09-13 20:06:12,352 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
    2013-09-13 20:06:12,354 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO zone (name) VALUES (%(name)s) RETURNING zone.id
    2013-09-13 20:06:12,354 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'name': 'zone_1'}
    2013-09-13 20:06:12,356 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK

    sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) relation "zone" does not exist
    LINE 1: INSERT INTO zone (name) VALUES ('zone_1') RETURNING zone.id
```

Why doesn't apply SQLAlchemy my schema? How can I fix it so it does apply my schema?

Comment: Is it working if you put everything in one script?

Comment: Nope, but when it does work in my setup method of my tests. I don't see the difference between my setup code and my load_fixture.py

Comment: Something is odd from the result and the code
I tried line by line and it fails with 
> TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
I changed `zone=Zone('zone_1')` for `zone=Zone(name='zone_1')` and worked.

It means that the default constructor is doing something else when not having named arguments.

Regarding the error you posted, it looks more related to a relationship between different classes, but there were no relationships in the posted Zone class or another class relating to it.